# Ruby Error: Expecting keyword_end?

Tags: ruby, debugging, syntax

Hey so I've got a small ruby program I wrote and everything is good except a syntax error that I for the life of me can not debug.Obviously, because of this my program is nor running.

My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def print_game_header
    # Print Header 
    print "\n" 
    print "Welcome to Math Buddy\n" 
    print "\n" 

end

def make_game_array game_array
    for x in 0..4
        for y in 0..4
            game_array[x][y] = "*"
        end
    end
end

def make_mines game_array
    for x in 0..4  
            game_array[x][rand(0..4)] = '!' 
        end
    end

def print_game_board game_array
    for x in 0..4
        for y in 0..4
        game_array[x][rand(0..4)]="!"
    end
end

def print_game_board game_array
    for x in 0..4
        for y in 0..4
            print game_array[x][y]              
            end
            print "\n"
        end
end

def compute_results game_array

        print "\nFor this 5x5 grid above, please give your guesses for the location of the mines in the following format #,#,#,#,# where # is a value of 1 through 5: "
        game_array = gets.chomp.split(',')

        print "\n"
        the_Guess = 0
        hits = 0
        for x in 0..4
            if game_array[x][guess_array[the_Guess].to_i-1] == '!'
                print "[#{x+1},#{guess_array[the_Guess]}] was a HIT!\n"
        else
            print "[#{x+1},#{guess_array[the_Guess]}] was a MISS!\n"
        end
        the_Guess+=1
    end
    if hits > 0
        print "\nYour hit rate was ", (hits.to_f/5*100).to_s, "%\n"
    else
        print "\nYour hit rate was 0%\n"
    end
end

columns, rows = 5, 5 
game_array = []  
rows.times { game_array << Array.new( columns ) }

print_game_header
make_game_array game_array
print_game_board game_array
make_mines game_array
compute_results

print "\nHere are the actual locations of the mines:\n\n"
print_game_board game_array
```

Comment: How do you know that "everything is good except a syntax error"?
Correct your indentation and you will debug error quickly.

Comment: Top tip: indent your code properly, then remove code bit by bit until the error goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition of `print_game_board` is missing and `end`.

Note: You define this method twice.